# SOAP returning invalid XML response

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework, soap

I'm using Zend_Soap_Client object for sending a soap request to another application here is the format of the XML that it's sending to the server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="urllocation" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"><env:Body><ns1:isAccountActive env:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"><param0 xsi:type="xsd:string">thisisatest</param0></ns1:isAccountActive></env:Body></env:Envelope>
```

I'm using it on the other SOAP servers that I have and seems to work fine but one of the server returned a response *"Invalid XML"* that is why I'm really wondering why *it won't work on that server alone*. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**Additional Details**:

I've tried to commentout the code that calls the method from the Server here is the code:

```
$client = new Zend_Soap_Client(null,
            array(
                'uri'=>'http://'.$user->customconfigs['alumniuri'],
                'encoding'=>'UTF-8',
                'location'=>'http://'.$user->customconfigs['alumnilocation']
            )
        );
        echo "Location: {$user->customconfigs['alumnilocation']} - uri: {$user->customconfigs['alumniuri']}";
        $alumniactive = $client->isAccountActive($token);
```

upon commenting out:

```
$alumniactive = $client->isAccountActive($token);
```

the error disappeared.This is the same codes from my other applications and it's working fine from there.

Comment: Perhaps the question is more about the server, if all the others work fine? ) What's the server in question, and does it work with any other clients in your disposal?

Comment: yeah it's more on the server and the same code is being used for all the other servers. I can't post the server location here for security purposes but the same logics are being used on all the other servers I've made. Perhaps there are any settings or part on the XML that I'm sending that maybe causing the problem and I'm really trying to figure it out where it could be coming from.

Comment: @raina77ow for your question if it would work on the other clients during disposal, yes it would work only this time I'm really frustrated tracing where this problem could be coming from.

Comment: hmmm.. try an if statement. then that bug will be fixed. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search for the answer to this question I finally found the problem... this code is actually located on a joomla component which I was using the uri same as what I have from the location that would include a character "&" which is illegal on xml standards removing these character from my xml will then cause the SOAP server to accept the request as valid. :)